# How to use LIKE in a dynamic sql search?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to do a dynamic case-insensitive search but im ending up with a Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

```
     java.sql.PreparedStatement preStatement = connect.prepareStatement
                            "SELECT word1 from words WHERE word2 like '%?%'");
     preStatement.setString(1, word);
     ResultSet rs = preStatement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement preStatement = connect.prepareStatement
                            "SELECT word1 from words WHERE word2 COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI like '?'");
preStatement.setString(1, "%"+word+"%");
ResultSet rs = preStatement.executeQuery();
```

when you are calling `setString()` api at that time use expression.

For case insensitive search you have to add `COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI` before like

Comment: Remove the single quote.

Comment: It removed the error, but it's returning null. Still can't do case-insensitive search

Comment: @Untitled I have updated my answer for case-insesitive serach

Comment: @atishshimpi it results to an error; com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: COLLATION 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'